# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - hibernation/suspend still working after turning it off

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I've upgraded my software to 20.04 lts version of Ubuntu and everything works fine but one thing isn't. In gnome settings I disabled automatic suspend but after ~15min of inactivity my computer (ye, it's PC) is going down. I'm not sure if it's suspend or hibernation, but I need to wait a while after using keyboard to pc gets back. It looks like my PC needs to get power, it's not like blank screen effect but turned off machine. [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOyaW.png)

How can I permamenty disable suspend/hibernation? My computer needs to run 24/7 after launching. Only blank screen is recommended (but even if the blank screen appear, PC has to be working)

When I used command

```
systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

I got response like this
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCEJk.png)

Comment: Lubuntu tag was added by mistake. My OS is ubuntu 20.04 lts (focal fossa probably as a full name). It was upgraded from 19.10. And yes, this picture is from gnome settings. I'm not sure what you mean as usage, but this PC needs to run constantly without any suspend/hibernation. Working from home and connecting to this pc via remote desktop needs a stable connection, but if I'm not active for ~15 minutes this machine is going down.

Comment: How I can achieve it? I mean, where is this config, or how to edit/disable it? In gnome settings there is no more options. In "power" tab every option was shown on image attached to post.

Comment: Do not have pictures of text induce the text and any additional info in the question not as comments.